# .filter() vs .get() for single object? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend, django-queryset

I was having a debate on this with some colleagues.  Is there a preferred way to retrieve an object in Django when you're expecting only one?

The two obvious ways are:

```
try:
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    # We have no object! Do something...
    pass
```

And:

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1)

if len(objs) == 1:
    obj = objs[0]
else:
    # We have no object! Do something...
    pass
```

The first method seems behaviorally more correct, but uses exceptions in control flow which may introduce some overhead.  The second is more roundabout but won't ever raise an exception.

Any thoughts on which of these is preferable?  Which is more efficient?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

[`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) is provided [specifically for this case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). Use it.

Option 2 is almost precisely how the `get()` method is actually implemented in Django, so there should be no "performance" difference (and the fact that you're thinking about it indicates you're violating one of the cardinal rules of programming, namely trying to optimize code before it's even been written and profiled -- until you have the code and can run it, you don't know how it will perform, and trying to optimize before then is a path of pain).

Comment: Everything is correct but maybe more info should be added to answer? 1. Python encourages try/except (see [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp)), that's why  `QS.get()` is good. 2. Details matter: does "expecting only one"  means always 0-1 objects, or it's possible to have 2+ objects and that case should be handled too (in this case `len(objs)` is a terrible idea)? 3. Don't assume anything about overhead without a benchmark (I think that in this case `try/except` will be faster as long as at least half of the calls return something)

Comment: > namely trying to optimize code before it's even been written and profiled  
This is an interesting remark. I always thought that I should think of the most optional way to implement something before implementing it. Is that wrong? Can you elaborate on this point? Is there some resource that explains this in detail?

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has mentioned first(). Other advice seems to indicate it's the call made for this scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123839/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-object-from-a-queryset-in-django

Comment: @ParthSharma The axiom I've heard for efficient development is "Working, pretty, fast." This doesn't preclude taking a moment to plan before implementing, but it keeps the focus on getting something to a usable state before spending time on optimizations that may never matter for the end user or purpose. The principle goes back (under many names) to at least 1983, in the book "Hints for Computer System Design." https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast

Comment: The only problem with using `get` is that it does not support certain query criteria (i.e., checking for _non_-equality), in which case `filter` with additional handling of multiple results is the only option.

Comment: What if I have only one record in my database? Like I have only one record and I don't know the pk value or anything else about the record. There is a validation in the ``save()`` method of the model class that ensures that there could be only one record in the model and all I need is to get that single record. I can do `model.objects.list()` to get it but then I need to use loops in my templates. Is there any way to get rid of that? Like something similar to `MyModel.object.get(pk)` with no parameters.

Answer (score 31):

You can install a module called [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/) and then do this:

```
from annoying.functions import get_object_or_None

obj = get_object_or_None(MyModel, id=1)

if not obj:
    #omg the object was not found do some error stuff
```

Comment: why is it annoying to have such a method ? looks fine to me !

Comment: @Thomas Without knowing the module I guess it is rather about providing functions to normally annoying django stuff.  
From their page (https://pypi.org/project/django-annoying/):  
> This is a django application that tries to eliminate annoying things in the Django framework.

Answer (score 20):

1 is correct. In Python an exception has equal overhead to a return. For a simplified proof you can look at [this](http://paltman.com/2008/jan/18/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/).

2 This is what Django is doing in the backend. `get` calls `filter` and raises an exception if no item is found or if more than one object is found.

Comment: That test is pretty unfair. A large part of the overhead in throwing an exception is the handling of the stack trace. That test had a stack length of 1 which is much lower than you would usually find in an application.

Comment: @Rob Young: What do you mean? Where do you see stack trace handling in the typical "ask forgiveness rather than permission" scheme? The processing time depends on the distance the exception travels, not how deep it all happens (when we're not writing in java and calling e.printStackTrace()). And most often (like in dictionary lookup) - the exception is thrown just below the `try`.

Answer (score 18):

I'm a bit late to the party, but with Django 1.6 there is the `first()` method on querysets.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first

---

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object. If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

Example:

```
p = Article.objects.order_by('title', 'pub_date').first()
Note that first() is a convenience method, the following code sample is equivalent to the above example:

try:
    p = Article.objects.order_by('title', 'pub_date')[0]
except IndexError:
    p = None
```

Comment: It doesn't guarantee that you have only one object in a query

Answer (score 11):

Why do all that work?  Replace 4 lines with 1 builtin shortcut. (This does its own try/except.)

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=1)
```

Comment: This is great when it's the desired behavior, but sometimes, you might want to create the missing object, or the pull was optional information.

Comment: That is what `Model.objects.get_or_create()` is for

Answer (score 8):

I can't speak with any experience of Django but option #1 clearly tells the system that you are asking for 1 object, whereas the second option does not. This means that option #1 could more easily take advantage of cache or database indexes, especially where the attribute you're filtering on is not guaranteed to be unique.

Also (again, speculating) the second option may have to create some sort of results collection or iterator object since the filter() call could normally return many rows. You'd bypass this with get().

Finally, the first option is both shorter and omits the extra temporary variable - only a minor difference but every little helps.

Comment: No experience with Django but still spot on.  Being explicit, terse & safe by default, are good principles no matter the language or framework.

Answer (score 7):

Some more info about exceptions.  If they are not raised, they cost almost nothing.  Thus if you know you are probably going to have a result, use the exception, since using a conditional expression you pay the cost of checking every time, no matter what.  On the other hand, they cost a bit more than a conditional expression when they are raised, so if you expect not to have a result with some frequency (say, 30% of the time, if memory serves), the conditional check turns out to be a bit cheaper.

But this is Django's ORM, and probably the round-trip to the database, or even a cached result, is likely to dominate the performance characteristics, so favor readability, in this case, since you expect exactly one result, use `get()`.

Answer (score 5):

I've played with this problem a bit and discovered that the option 2 executes two SQL queries, which for such a simple task is excessive. See my annotation:

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1) # This does not execute any SQL
if len(objs) == 1: # This executes SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXX WHERE filter
    obj = objs[0]  # This executes SELECT x, y, z, .. FROM XXX WHERE filter
else: 
    # we have no object!  do something
    pass
```

An equivalent version that executes a single query is:

```
items = [item for item in MyModel.objects.filter(id=1)] # executes SELECT x, y, z FROM XXX WHERE filter
count = len(items) # Does not execute any query, items is a standard list.
if count == 0:
   return None
return items[0]
```

By switching to this approach, I was able to substantially reduce number of queries my application executes.

Comment: It is a clear note. many thanks

Answer (score 3):

**.get()**

> Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters, which should
>   be in the  format described in Field lookups.
>
> get() raises MultipleObjectsReturned if more than one object was
>   found. The MultipleObjectsReturned exception is an attribute of the
>   model class.
>
> get() raises a DoesNotExist exception if an object wasn't found for
>   the given parameters. This exception is also an attribute of the model
>   class.

**.filter()**

> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup
>   parameters.

**Note**

> use get() when you want to get a single unique object, and filter()
>   when you want to get all objects that match your lookup parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, but for me option #2 reeks of premature optimisation. I'm not sure which is more performant, but option #1 certainly looks and feels more pythonic to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different design.

If you want to perform a function on a possible result, you could derive from QuerySet, like this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/

The result is pretty awesome, you could for example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).yourFunction()
```

Here, filter returns either an empty queryset or a queryset with a single item. Your custom queryset functions are also chainable and reusable. If you want to perform it for all your entries: `MyModel.objects.all().yourFunction()`.

They are also ideal to be used as actions in the admin interface:

```
def yourAction(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.yourFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is more elegant, but be sure to use try..except.

From my own experience I can tell you that sometimes you're sure there cannot possibly be more than one matching object in the database, and yet there will be two... (except of course when getting the object by its primary key).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add one more take on this issue, but I am using the django paginator, and in my data admin app, the user is allowed to pick what to query on.  Sometimes that is the id of a document, but otherwise it is a general query returning more than one object, i.e., a Queryset.

If the user queries the id, I can run:

```
Record.objects.get(pk=id)
```

which throws an error in django's paginator, because it is a Record and not a Queryset of Records.

I need to run:

```
Record.objects.filter(pk=id)
```

Which returns a Queryset with one item in it. Then the paginator works just fine.

Comment: To use the paginator - or any functionality that expects a QuerySet - your query must return a QuerySet. Don't switch between using .filter() and .get(), stick with .filter() and supply the "pk=id" filter, as you have already realised. That is the pattern for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

[get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) returns one object as shown below:

```js
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "26",
  "gender": "Male"
}
```

[filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/) which has one or more objects as shown below:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "26",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": "18",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "name": "Marry",
    "age": "22",
    "gender": "Female"
  }
]
```