# Django ModelChoiceField returning index. Want to get object at that position

Tags: python, django, html-select, django-queryset

I have a webpage where you can add a new computer/ip to the database, or choose a previously added from a dropdown list. Everything works fine, except that what I get after the user is selecting an item from the list is the index of it, and not its name. 
How can I get the name? I am trying to access the queryset as a vector as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123839/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-object-from-a-queryset-in-django), but I get a TypeError.

views.py:

```
d = DropDownList(request.POST or None)
    if d.is_valid():
        c = request.POST.get('current')
        return HttpResponse(d.qs[c-1])
```

models.py:

```
class DropDownList(forms.Form):
    qs = Computer.objects.all().order_by('name')
    current = forms.ModelChoiceField(qs, widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'submit()'}))    

class Computer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

home.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ current }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using a form is that it takes care of validation and data conversion, so in your view you should get the data from the form, not from the POST itself.

```
if d.is_valid():
    c = d.cleaned_data['current']
```