# How to get a model object with the lowest ID?

Tags: python, django

I want to get the model object with the lowest ID, in other words the oldest object in that field.

```
oldest = Model.objects.filter(id=lowest_number)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.first()` and `.order_by()`.

```
oldest = Model.objects.order_by('id').first()
```

Or if you are sure that the queryset isn't empty then you can use slicing.

```
oldest = Model.objects.order_by('id')[0]
```

Have a look at the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#first).

**EDIT:**

You can also use `.earliest()`.

```
oldest = Model.objects.earliest('id')
```

Here's the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#earliest).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123839/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-object-from-a-queryset-in-django).