# What does Django return if no objects are found? And why do I get a DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a MySQL table in which I have Django register that a certain user is 'connected' to a unit. For this I have to check if the unit is allready connected to some other user. (model: AppUnitSession)

So in my function I get three objects (models) as input (user, usersession, vehicle)

The problem I have is that my query for the AppUnitSession fails with a

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist 
Exception Value: AppUnitSession matching query does not exist.
```

This error occurs on the first line of this code:

```
sessions = AppUnitSession.objects.get(gps_unit_id=vehicle.gps_unit_id)
sessions = sessions.exclude(validation_date__isnull=True)
sessions = sessions.exclude(user_session_id=usersession.user_session_id)
```

from the call stack I can see that value for the vehicle.gps_unit_id is set:

```
{'gps_unit_id': 775L}
```

There are NO records in the AppUnitSession table that match this! all records in this table have gps_units_id = NULL (ea, the unit is available and the user can continue and after this there will be a record with the gps_unit_id set. If there are sessions found, I need do some more work.

For the start I don't want the error. But also I want something I can iterate over or check it's length (>1) do some more checks.

I'm a bit stuck on this one, so help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `filter` instead of `get` but filter returns list of objects while get returns an object if found.

Use `sessions = AppUnitSession.objects.filter(gps_unit_id=vehicle.gps_unit_id)`

instead of `#sessions = AppUnitSession.objects.get(gps_unit_id=vehicle.gps_unit_id)`

Other approach if you only want to get rid of error is to perform `exception handling`:

```
try:
    sessions = AppUnitSession.objects.get(gps_unit_id=vehicle.gps_unit_id)
    sessions = sessions.exclude(validation_date__isnull=True)
    sessions = sessions.exclude(user_session_id=usersession.user_session_id)
except AppUnitSession.DoesNotExist:
    #some code when the object does not exists
```

But, it is better to use `get` rather than `filter` if you are trying to retrieve only one object. Read performance of get vs filter for one object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018886/django-filter-versus-get-for-single-object).

Comment: you cant use `exclude` on `get` result (`AppUnitSession` instance) and there is no perfomance issues actually if `filter` used to get one object...

Comment: npdu is right. You have to `exclude` first and `get`in the end.