# How Entry.objects.filter() or Entry.objects.get() works?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How do `Entry.objects.filter()` or `Entry.objects.get()` work?

Do they scan the whole database one by one and then give the resulting object?

What happens when we do search on the primary key value of objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter versus get for single object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018886/django-filter-versus-get-for-single-object)

Comment: No. Why would they do that? They send SELECT...WHERE queries to the database.

Comment: "filter" will give you an array of objects while "get" will return an object and an error if nothing was found.

Comment: take a look at [db_index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on your models, to add index on specific field. If you don't have indexes , your sgbd do a fullscan (normal case in SQL I think).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

Methods that **do not** return **QuerySets**

`get(**kwargs)`

Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters, which should be in the format described in Field lookups.

`get()` raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one object was found. The `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception is an attribute of the model class.

`get()` raises a `DoesNotExist` exception if an object wasn’t found for the given parameters. This exception is an attribute of the model class.

---

Methods that return **new QuerySets**:

`filter(**kwargs)`

Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.

---

In a nutshell: `get()` returns a single unique object and `filter()` returns all the objects that match your lookup parameters.